# "Animating" background on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I've been trying to animate a "background" for a project I'm doing on a canvas. I'm using raphaelJS, and what I'm doing is

```
function bg(){

    h = 0;

    var terra = paper.rect(0, 500 + h, 900, 100);
    terra.attr({'fill': '#00E639', 'stroke': 'none'});

    var troposfera = paper.rect(0, -100 + h, 900, 600);
    troposfera.attr({'fill': '#C0866D', 'stroke': 'none'});

    var estratosfera = paper.rect(0, -700 + h, 900, 600);
    estratosfera.attr({'fill': '#4497BF', 'stroke': 'none'});

    var ozono = paper.rect(0, -900 + h, 900, 600);
    ozono.attr({'fill': '#E8EAE9', 'stroke': 'none'});

    var mesosfera = paper.rect(0, -1500 + h, 900, 600);
    mesosfera.attr({'fill': '#434392', 'stroke': 'none'});

    var termosfera = paper.rect(0, -2100 + h, 900, 600);
    termosfera.attr({'fill': '#3A435A', 'stroke': 'none'});

    var exosfera = paper.rect(0, -2700 + h, 900, 300);
    exosfera.attr({'fill': '#000000', 'stroke': 'none'});
}
```

and then calling it under a setInterval as such

```
var drbg = setInterval(function(){
    bg();
    h = h + 1;
}, 40);
```

However, it's not working. It paints the background, but then does not move up as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the first line in `bg()` is `h=0;`, which resets `h` to `0` every time you call it...

to make it work, try moving `h=0;` out of bg()

Comment: Didn't even see it >.> Thanks mate!